# How do you list My Images on Azure using the Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I am using the Azure Java SDK to list available images for creating virtual machines. When I use:

```
ComputeManagementService.create(config).ComputeManagementClient().getVirtualMachineOSImagesOperations().list().getImages();
```

It only lists the gallery images available and not my custom images. I have seen other topics that cover SDKs for other languages or using PowerShell but I would like to do this with the Java SDK for Azure.

Does anyone know how to use the Java SDK for Azure to get a list of My Images?

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious - have you also tried running `getVirtualMachineVMImagesOperations()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David is correct. Please try getVirtualMachineVMImagesOperations. One year ago, VM images have replaced OS images. So all your custom images now are VM images. Please refer to http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/vm-image-entity/ for more information.